# Google cloud's glcoud compute instance create gives error "The resource projects/{ourID}/global/images/family/debian-8 was not found

Tags: command-line, google-cloud-platform

We are using a server I created on **Google Cloud Platform** to create and manage the other servers over there. But when trying to create a new server from the Linux command line with the GCloud compute instances create function we receive the following error:

```
marco@ans-mgmt-01:~/gcloud$ ./create_gcloud_instance.sh app-tst-04 tst,backend-server,bootstrap home-tst 10.20.22.104
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
- The resource 'projects/REMOVED_OUR_PROJECTID/global/images/family/debian-8' was not found
```

Our script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
if [ "$#" -ne 4 ]; then                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    echo "Usage: create_gcloud_instance <instance_name> <tags> <subnet_name> <server_ip>"                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    exit 1
fi

set -e

INSTANCE_NAME=$1
TAGS=$2
SERVER_SUBNET=$3
SERVER_IP=$4

gcloud compute --project "REMOVED OUR PROJECT ID" instances create "$INSTANCE_NAME" \
    --zone "europe-west1-c" \
    --machine-type "f1-micro" \
    --network "cloudnet" \
    --subnet "$SERVER_SUBNET" \
    --no-address \
    --private-network-ip="$SERVER_IP" \
    --maintenance-policy "MIGRATE" \
    --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" \
    --service-account "default" \
    --tags "$TAGS" \
    --image-family "debian-8" \
    --boot-disk-size "10" \
    --boot-disk-type "pd-ssd" \
    --boot-disk-device-name "bootdisk-$INSTANCE_NAME" \


./clean_known_hosts.sh $INSTANCE_NAME
```

On the google cloud console (console.cloud.google.com) I enabled the cloud api access scope for the ans-mgmt-01 server and also tried to create a server from there. That's working without problems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that gcloud is looking for the image family in your project and not the debian-cloud project where it really exists.

This can be fixed by simply using `--image-project debian-cloud`.

This way instead of looking for `projects/{yourID}/global/images/family/debian-8`, it will look for `projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-8`.

Comment: the above error also occurs when using `gcloud deployment-manager deployments create ....` only there's no `--image-project` flag there :(

Comment: In that case you need to use a full path that includes the project as the image. For Debian, that would be `projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-9`

Comment: Thanks! I actually copied an example straight from google's documentation which specified: `https://googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-8` (see [this example](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-configuration#add_properties_to_your_resource)). But then I saw [this other example](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-basic-configuration#declaring_a_resource_type) which is exactly what you suggest and it works... I should open a new SO thread about it I guess but I'm too lazy....

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was debian-8(and now debian-9) reached the end of life and no longer supported. Updating to debian-10 or debian-11 fixed the issue

Comment: And now same problem with debian-9. So instead of updating like 9,10,11... first find using 'gcloud compute images list | grep debian' then use from list

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was debian-9 after so much time came to an end and tried updating to debian-10  fixed the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you could run below command to see if the image is available

```
gcloud compute images list | grep debian
```

Below is the result from the command

```
NAME: debian-10-buster-v20221206
PROJECT: debian-cloud
FAMILY: debian-10
NAME: debian-11-bullseye-arm64-v20221102
PROJECT: debian-cloud
FAMILY: debian-11-arm64
NAME: debian-11-bullseye-v20221206
PROJECT: debian-cloud
FAMILY: debian-11
```

So you could have some idea from your result